# Define variables to load MNIST images app

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I'm learning ML with TensorFlow and then I've a simple MNIST model.

This is the model code, following the official tutorial

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
for _ in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Now, I'd like to practice with this model by passing number images.
So, the question is how can I make (in Python) to define a variable to load in an image (.bmp, .jpg,
.png...). The idea is to **first practice with local files in my computer** and later being able
to **send image data from a client** (supposedly, via JSON in a REST API way) to the model
to show the prediction about which number appears in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Python PIL package to load the image:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
```

Convert it to a numpy array, everything you pass to tensorflow has to be in numpy format:

```
import numpy as np
img3d = np.array(im)
```

These images are currently shaped [28, 28] or [28, 28, 1], reshape them to 784:

```
img_flat = np.reshape(img3d, (1, 784))
```

You'll want to batch together a number of these, use `tf.vstack` to combine them.